# About how to specify which one to call after overloading the set method of an entity class

Tags: mybatis

I defined a dto, it has a field which is a list of permissions, and I used a multi-table association to query it out as a string separated by ',' which I want to automatically convert to a list when I want to map to an entity class, so I overloaded the method, but this way it will only call the method with a list parameter, and when I comment the method with a list parameter, it's me Yes (calling a method with a string argument), I wonder if there is a way to specify the overloaded method he calls

This is dto

```
package com.dingdong.main.dto;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author 乔治
 * @date 2023/11/10
 */
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ApiModel(value = "PathDTO", description = "前端展示的路径信息")
public class PathDTO {

    @ApiModelProperty(value="唯一索引")
    private Integer id;

    @ApiModelProperty(value="路径")
    private String requestPath;

    @ApiModelProperty(value="请求方式")
    private String requestMethod;

    @ApiModelProperty(value="路径描述")
    private String describe;

    @ApiModelProperty(value="路径权限集合")
    private List<String> permissions;

    public void setPermissionsStr(String permissions) {
        this.permissions = Arrays.asList(permissions.split(", "));
    }


}
```

This is the data I queried

| id | request_path | request_method | describe | permissions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 37 | /clock/changeClock | GET | 切换打卡是否开始 |  |
| 38 | /device/isVip | POST | 验证设备是否授权(无需操作) |  |
| 39 | /role/getRole | GET |  | "query, add" |
| 40 | /user/signUp | POST |  | "change, query" |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @user22457778 Please replace the images with text ([why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1261766)). Markdown supports syntax coloring and tables. You can simply rename the setter method to `setPermissionsStr(String str)` and change the column alias from `permissions` to `permissionsStr`.

Comment: All right. Thank you.